# I want to use out_file on Python

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I'm studying Python for two months. My goal is to do the sentiment analysis! But self-study is too hard, so I want to ask for help.

1. I collected data from Twitter API, and I put the data to notepad. It is too long like that. `{created_at":"Fri Nov 03 03:28:33 +0000 2017", ~~ id, tweet, unicode}`
2. I converted data to simple on IPython console(Spyder). It's like `"Fri Nov 03 03:46:46 +0000 2017 @user blah blah [hash tags] time stamp"`. Then I want to put the simple data to notepad again. The code is written as follows. How can I change the code on part of `out_file`?

   ```
   try:
       import json

   except ImportError:
       import simplejson as json

   tweets_filename = 'C:/Users/ID500/Desktop/SA/Corpus/siri/siri_0.txt' #Not converted data

   tweets_file = open(tweets_filename, "r")

   for line in tweets_file:
       try:
           tweet = json.loads(line.strip())
           if 'text' in tweet:
               print (tweet['id'])
               print (tweet['created_at'])
               print (tweet['text'])

               print (tweet['user']['id'])
               print (tweet['user']['name'])
               print (tweet['user']['screen_name'])

               hashtags = []
               for hashtag in tweet['entities']['hashtags']:
                   hashtags.append(hashtag['text'])
               print(hashtags)
               out_file = open("C:/Users/ID500/Desktop/SA/Corpus/final/fn_siri_1.txt", 'a') # I want to put data to that path.
               out_file.write() # What can I write here?
               out_file.close()

       except:
           continue
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: You have no function so return won't work there

Comment: I had a mistake.. I edited it!

Comment: `json` *is* `simplejson` in modern Python. In older versions, you might try to import `simplejson` first, using the (standard library version of)) `json` as a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open two files at once. Don't open one within the loop

For example

```
open(tweets_filename) as tweets_file, open(output, "a") as out_file:
    for line in tweets_file:
        # parse the line here 
        out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: I understood what you said. But the converted data cannot be contained within the note pad.. Just unconverted data saved in notepad. How can I try this?

Comment: You obviously will need to modify the line list to do what you need, or build a new one